# Advice for database choice and architecture for implementing a Human Resource web app

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm currently developing a Human Resource web app for my friend's company and I'm still undecided whether to choose a Relational or NoSQL database, or maybe a hybrid. I’m quite intrigued of the use cases of these NoSQL databases, reason why I entertained the thought of using them for this project.

A sample scenario for the relations in the database:

> An employee has many (can be none or many):
>
> - educational background records
> - training and certification records
> - work experience records
> - volunteer records
> - organization and other info records

Also, much work will be on the decision-support aspect of the app, like determining career paths and developing succession plans for employees.

Would it be feasible to go to the NoSQL route? Based on the relationships, the database has many one-to-many relationship centering on the employees table. Would choosing a NoSQL over a RDBMS offer benefits in terms of querying and performance? MongoDB was my preferred choice (well, since it’s the only NoSQL database I’ve read about).

Also, how do I deal with pictures of employees and scanned documents and pictures of certificates? Last time I used MySQL for an app that saved pictures as BLOBs in the database, it ended up less responsive during data querying and lookup.

Comment: If you will have extensive relationship handling, concurrent requests, consistency challenges (likely with production systems) and will be performing large aggregations of large amounts of sensitive data then go with Relational database. If you primarily require speed and data consistency/relations are not as important (likely with web-apps) and will be dealing with complex text-based queries then go with NoSQL. The better option would be to try both and then evaluate their performance because you will get varied opinions here. All the best.

Comment: @Sai I agree with the evaluation of performance. With regards to it, does it mean using the tools (bundled or proprietary) that are made specifically to measure them, i.e., mysql performance monitoring tools, tools for mongodb, and the like...

Comment: You could use the specific tools to measure their performance or you could use your own metrics. If you are going to use tools, I'm pretty sure that several use cases will have already been compared by someone and will be available online. But for your specific use case, you can try comparing their performance using tools as well. :)

Comment: Please read a data modeling book that covers this, before you start. Enterprise Model Patterns by Hay or Data Model Resource Book (vols 1,2) by Silverston

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decision to go with a relational database or a NoSQL database will largely depend on a number of factors:

- How the data you need to be stored is to be modeled.
- What the expected access pattern for the data is to be
- What requirements you have for scalability
- What requirements you have for data consistency

Typically NoSQL might be preferable when you have:

- A schema-less or dynamic data structure.
- No need to access the data outside of using a handful of indexes (i.e. you don't need much flexibility in how you access the data)
- You have the need to scale horizontally (something traditionally more difficult to do with relational DB's)
- You maybe don't need transactional consistency and are possibly OK with eventual read consistency (depending on the NoSQL system you choose)

To me the usage you listed would seem to be more in-line with what you might see in a typical relational DB-backed application.  That is not to suggest that you should ONLY use a relational DB. I think any sufficiently complex set of inter-related services that need to achieve high scalability might have needs for a wide array of data storage mechanisms - relational DB's, NoSQL, in-memory caching, persistent flat file storage, etc.  You will just need to look at incorporating these as your needs dictate.

Regarding your comment on image storage.  I have found that there are very few cases where storing images in a database makes sense. For most cases, storing references to image locations (filepaths, URL's, etc.) would be the preferred approach.